# Scala compile error: member of method parameter not visible to class method

Tags: scala, default-constructor

I am getting a compile error of:

```
value txn is not a member of Charge
new Charge(this.txn + that.txn)
                           ^
```

with the following Scala class definition:

```
class Charge(txn: Double = 0){
  def combine(that:Charge): Charge = 
    new Charge(this.txn + that.txn)
}
```

Explicitly declaring txn as a val allows it to work:

```
class Charge(val txn: Double = 0){
  def combine(that:Charge): Charge = 
    new Charge(this.txn + that.txn)
}
```

I thought val was assumed? Can somebody explain this? Is it a problem with my understanding of the default constructor or the scope of the method?

Comment: val is not assumed for a regular class constructor parameter. It's assumed for case class only.

Comment: Okay; then if if won't imply val/var for regular classes, why would defining `class Charge(txn:Double)` be possible? I guess this is how I got confused...

Comment: Don't really understand your question. txn without val is just a parameter like in a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scala, you can define classes in two forms, for ex.

- `class Charge(txn: Double)` -> In this case scala compiler compiles it to java like below

```java
public class Charge {
  ....
  public Charge combine(Charge);
  ....
  public Charge(double);
  ....
}
```

As you can notice in compiled java code, there is no public accessor for `txn`
Let's look at another variation of `Charge` class,
If you define like this `class Charge(val txn: String)`, it gets compiled to below

```java
public class Charge {

  ...
  public double txn();
  ...  
  public Charge combine(Charge);
  ...
  public Charge(double);
  ...
}
```

As you can see, in this case compiler generates `public` accessor for `txn` hence you are able to access `that.txn` when you mark it as `val`

- `case class Charge(txn: Double)`: This is data class for which scala generates `getters`, `equals` and `toString` for you. 
  You can compile this class
- `scalac Charge.scala`
- `javap -c Charge.class` 
  And then see what it generates

Answer (score 2):

What you pass to constructor is essentially constructor parameters whose scope is limited to the constructor. If you want to make them visible from the outside, you have to declare them as vals or reassign to some other vals in the constructor body.